# SpringSecurity seems to be encrypting my download files

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm developing a MVC web where you can download stuff, and everything was working as intended until today. I decided to incorporate Spring Security in order to protect my URLs from not authorized access and that stuff.

I've managed to implement it without major issues, but I noticed something really weird. Prior to implementing Spring Security, I could download PDF files from the website, but after all that I can get is a chunk of data:
[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F7GA.png)

My code to serve the files is the following:

```
public void getPdfBook(String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
        PropertiesDAO properties = (PropertiesDAO) context.getBean("propertiesDAO");
        String path = properties.getDirectory();

        try {
            File file = new File(path + File.separator + fileName);

            if (file.exists()) {
                FileUtils.copyFile(file, response.getOutputStream());

                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
                response.flushBuffer();
            } else {
                System.out.println("File Not Found on: " + path + File.separator + fileName);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And my Spring Security URL configuration is the next (along with other stuff):

```
<security:http pattern="/registerUser" security="none" />
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
    login-processing-url="/authenticateUser"
    default-target-url="/"
    authentication-failure-url="/login"
    username-parameter="username"
    password-parameter="password"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newBook" access="hasAuthority('AUTH_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyAuthority('AUTH_USER', 'AUTH_ADMIN')" />
    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-url="/logout" />
</security:http>
```

The URL used to download the PDF is "/getPdfBook", which is in the "/**" pattern. I can do the request, but the result is wrong (the image I posted).

Can someone help? Thank you!!

PS: If i disable the Spring Security for that URL using  then it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Changed that code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
```

To this one:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
```